# How do I send a recurring email on Outlook 365?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'd like to schedule a recurring email to be sent every week from my Outlook 365 account, that will be sent even if I'm offline or don't user Outlook at the moment.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

If your Office 365 subscription includes
[Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/),
a scheduled flow can be used as follows.

1. Create a new Flow with a "Schedule" trigger.
2. Show advanced options for the trigger.
3. Set the Frequency to **Monthly** ; set Interval to 1; select your time zone;
   and set the start date.
   For example, use `2017-07-26T00:00:00Z` to start at midnight UTC the 26th day of every month.
4. Set the Action to `Office 365 / Send an email`. Show Advanced options if needed, and complete filling in needed fields.
5. Give your flow a name and save it.

On the saved flow page, you may use the `... More` button to run the flow
immediately for testing.

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/6pse8c/recurring_emails/)

Comment: When you use the prepared "send mail on a schedule" template, you need to fill in your mail server and credentials. This fails when 2FA is enabled. However, when you start from a blank template and add these steps by hand, it uses your O365 credentials and mail server - this does work!

Comment: Just a note that "Microsoft Flow" now seems to be called "Power Automate"