# Outlook 365: Send the same email every month at a specific day of the week

Tags: office365

I have a web account in Outlook 365 and wanted to know if it was possible to send the same email the last Tuesday of every month? I've been told about Flow, but my work account does not have it included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send a recurring email on Outlook 365?](https://superuser.com/questions/1323457/how-do-i-send-a-recurring-email-on-outlook-365)

Comment: Unfortunately, my organization doesn't have access to Flow